# Jordan product in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, algebra

Does anyone know how to best handle non-associative operations in Mathematica? I am specifically interested in finite commutative Jordan algebras.

I would like to construct a product operator x such that if I write out expressions like AxB + 7BxA, or A^2(BA) - (A^2B)A, then mathematica will simplify them to expressions like 8AxB and 0 respectively.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the fact that Jordan algebras can be constructed from the associative algebras:

```
CircleDot[a_, b_] := 1/2 (a.b + b.a)
```

For the latter, one can use, e.g., matrix representations. Let us make an example:

```
A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
B = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
```

We verify now your equations with respect to `CircleDot`:

```
(A ⊙ B + 7 B ⊙ A - 8 A ⊙ B)//Norm//Chop
 (*0*)

((A ⊙ A) ⊙ (B ⊙ A) - ((A ⊙ A) ⊙ B) ⊙ A)//Norm//Chop
 (*0*)
```

### Final mathematical remarks

One may oppose to the above construction with the argument that it only covers *special Jordan algebras*. Well, true, there are indeed *exceptional Jordan algebras*. However, they are rather scarce and not so useful for applications in quantum mechanics. Here, I would like to cite a passage from McCrimmon's
"*A Taste of Jordan Algebras*":

> In 1983 Zel’manov proved the astounding theorem that any simple Jordan
>   algebra, of arbitrary dimension, is either (1) an algebra of Hermitian
>   elements $\mathcal{H}(A,∗)$ for a ∗-simple associative algebra with involution,
>   (2) an algebra of spin type determined by a nondegenerate quadratic
>   form, or (3) an Albert algebra of dimension 27 over its center. This
>   brought an end to the search for an exceptional setting for quantum
>   mechanics: it is an ineluctable fact of mathematical nature that
>   simple algebraic systems obeying the basic laws of Jordan must
>   (outside of dimension 27) have an invisible associative support behind
>   them.